# Adobe Flash plugin: no full screen

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, flash, fullscreen

in my Lubuntu 13.04 (with Gnome Shell 3.8), Flash videos won't go to full screen in certain Flash players (i.e. on certain sites).
- Actually in most players, that means it doesn't work at all. Upon left-click on the fullscreen-button, I see a flicker as if it did got to full-screen, but then it stays standard size, kinda like a pop-up ad being killed by ad-block.
- Some players have a "toggle fullscreen" option available on right-click menu, this is the only option that works for me now. In this case, I have to press and hold the right mouse button and release it over the "fullscreen" menu entry. The menu disappears when releasing the mouse button.
- Only exception I found so far: Youtube, which works normally with left click on the fullscreen-button.
My current Flash-plugin version is 11.2.202.285ubuntu0.13.04.1.
I wonder if Gnome Shell might be messing with Flash?
Is anyone else experiencing this problem?
Edit: this problem is present in Firefox, Opera and Chromium browsers.
The graphics card I'm using (as reported in Gnome settings > details) is GeForce 8100/nForce720a/integrated/SSE2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the following solution which worked perfectly for me:

Workaround fo this:

1. Install devilspie (via Terminal:)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install devilspie
   ```
2. Write config for firefox (via Terminal:)

   ```
   mkdir ~/.devilspie
   nano ~/.devilspie/flash-fullscreen-firefox.ds

   (if
   (is (application_name) "plugin-container")
   (begin
   (focus)
   )
   )
   ```
3. Make devilspie autostart

Done.﻿

Solution from:
https://plus.google.com/100368718538258540940/posts/eJWwPj8B4dX (last post)

Comment: I'm stuck at step 3. How do you make a command line appplication autostart? Remember I'm on Lubuntu 13.04 with Gnome Shell.

Comment: here's how I made the autostart work: in Gnome dash, search for "Startprogramme" (means autostart applications - my UI is in German!). In terminal, type: which devilspie , output: /usr/bin/devilspie . In "Startprogramme", click "add" and insert this output in the "command" field. Fullscreen Flash is now working again.

Answer (score 0):

I created a devilspie script to make flash play videos full screen in Chromium and Firefox.

Save the following snippet to a file, make it executable and run it.
(Tested on Fedora Linux 19 using yum instead of apt-get)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

sudo yum install devilspie

mkdir -p ~/.devilspie

echo '(if
(or
    (is (application_name) "plugin-container")
    (and
        (contains application_name) "chromium-browser")
        (contains application_name) "flash-plugin")
    )
)
(begin
(focus)
)
)' > ~/.devilspie/flash_fullscreen.ds

echo '#!/bin/bash

echo "running" > /home/maarten/devilspie.log

while [ true ]; do
  /usr/bin/devilspie;
done' > ~/.devilspie/devilspie_daemon.sh

chmod a+x ~/.devilspie/devilspie_daemon.sh

mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart

echo '[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/maarten/.devilspie/devilspie_daemon.sh
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Devilspie Daemon
Name=Devilspie Daemon
Comment[en_US]=Script will continuously restart devilspie if stopped
Comment=Script will continuously restart devilspie if stopped
' > ~/.config/autostart/devilspie_daemon.desktop
```